# Flex: Remove drop shadow from ApplicationControlBar?

Tags: apache-flex

Does anyone know how to remove the default drop shadow from ApplicationControlBar?

I tried this but no luck:

```
<mx:Style>
        global
        {
            dropShadowEnabled:false;
        }
    </mx:Style>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dropShadowEnabled can only be set in MXML mode but not in design mode. I don't know why it's not documented feature.

This works for me:

```
<mx:ApplicationControlBar width="80%" dropShadowEnabled="false">
        <mx:Button label="Test"></mx:Button>
</mx:ApplicationControlBar>
```

Comment: I am seeing compilation error:The style 'dropShadowEnabled' is excluded by type 'mx.containers.ApplicationControlBar'. This is my code: <mx:ApplicationControlBar x="1" y = "1" width="520" dock="false" fillAlphas="[0.5, 0.5]" dropShadowEnabled="false">

Answer (score 1):

At runtime:

```
applicationcontrolbar.setStyle('dropShadowEnabled',"false");
```